# How to obtain FPS using mp4parser?

Tags: java, mp4parser

Framerate can be calculated as

> > FPS = framescale / timescale

Timescale is easy to obtain using `isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getTimescale()`

But I cannot figure out where is the framescale stored within the mp4parser isobox structure.

Some sample code I came across [here](https://gist.github.com/OllieJones/5ffb011fa3a11964154975582360391c) uses low-level buffer read on the following path: `/moov/trak/mdhd`,  but that doesn't seem to be accessible using mp4parser.

**Question:**
Is it possible to extract framescale and/or framerate using mp4parser? Or is it better to use ffmpeg instead?

*Note: I prefer using native libraries such as mp4parser over external executables (ffmpeg) where possible*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question, but here is how you can get the frame rate using Mp4Parser:

```
for(int i=0; i<video.getTracks().size();i++){
    Track videoTrack = video.getTracks().get(i);
    if(videoTrack.getHandler().equals("vide)){
        TrackMetaData metaData = videoTrack.getTrackMetaData();
        //Get timescale
        long timeScale = metaData.getTimescale();
        //Get video duration in Us
        long durationUs = videoTrack.getDuration() * 1000 *1000 / timeScale;
        //Get total frames
        long totalFrames = videoTrack.getSamples().size();
        //Calculate the frame duration
        long perFrameDurationUs =  durationUs /  totalFrames;
        //FPS
        long fps = 1000 * 1000 / perFrameDurationUs;
    }
}
```

`video` is refering to `Movie video = MovieCreator.build(filePath);`